# Use case for F# Choice type

Tags: f#

I've been aware of the [F# Choice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353591.aspx) type for a while , but can't think of any place I'd use it rather than defining my own [union type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233226.aspx) with meaningful named cases.

The MSDN documentation doesn't offer much advice ("Helper types for active patterns with two choices.") and doesn't have any example usages.

I must be missing something - what are the key advantages of this type over a custom union?

Comment: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx/blob/master/tests/FSharpx.Tests/ChoiceTests.fs https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx/blob/master/tests/FSharpx.Tests/ValidationTests.fs https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx/blob/master/tests/FSharpx.Tests/ValidationExample.fs

Comment: Which is similar to Haskell's Either http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Either.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my opinion the use cases for the `Choice` type are quite similar to the use cases for tuple types.  In either case, you will often want to define your own more specific type which is isomorphic to the type (a custom DU for choices; a custom record type for tuples).  Nonetheless, over limited scopes or in very generic situations (where good naming may become difficult), it's nice to have anonymous variants.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't considered the similarity to tuples, especially with regard to naming in generic situations.

Comment: However, with tuples I almost never have to access the elements via fst or snd because I can pattern match directly into more meaningful named values. It is slightly more clunky with a Choice.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, a more specific union type might be nice for a particular situation, but having a general Choice union means that your code can mesh well with other code when using general constructs such as Workflows, Functors, etc.

IIRC there's not an implementation of the Either Monad (Workflow in F# lingo) in the standard FSharp Core library, but there is one in the FSharpx library (<del>though I couldn't find a constructor for it so I had to roll my own</del> thanks to @MauricioScheffer for poiting me to `choose`).

From my limited, mostly C# interop, F# experience, Choice and Option aren't baked into F#'s standard methods as much as Haskell's Maybe and Either algebraic data types are baked into its standard libraries, so you don't get as much of a "this is useful" sense when using them in F# as you might in Haskell, but they are quite useful.

As for an example: in an application I recently wrote I returned Choice1Of2 from methods when I had a successful result and Choice2Of2 with an error message when something went wrong -- whether an exception being caught or a precondition not being met -- and ran my code in a Workflow for flow control. This is one standard use of this union type.

Comment: See https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx/blob/master/tests/FSharpx.Tests/ChoiceTests.fs#L69

Comment: @MauricioScheffer  ah, it's `choose`! Thanks!

Comment: [ExtCore](https://nuget.org/packages/ExtCore/) also contains an implementation of the "Either" workflow (called `choice`) and loads of utility functions for working with Choice values: https://github.com/jack-pappas/ExtCore

Comment: @MauricioScheffer ExtCore is **not** a fork of FSharpx -- it's mostly my own code (the rest is code I've adapted from other functional languages), and it's something I started working on before FSharpx was available. If you want to collaborate, DM me on twitter or start a new thread on fsharp-opensource and we can discuss it.

Comment: @JackP. Thanks for letting me know about that, it's always nice to learn of a lib's existence

Comment: @JackP. Sorry, didn't mean "fork" that way. I just think it would be nice to pool our efforts into a single base library, it would make the most out of the small F# community.

Comment: Thanks Paul, very thorough answer. In the success/failure example you gave, I would use a Result union with Success and Failure cases as described in http://lucabolognese.wordpress.com/2012/11/23/exceptions-vs-return-values-to-represent-errors-in-f-iithe-critical-monad/. Maybe it just comes down to personal preference?

Comment: @Akash I would have liked using a Result union with Success/Failure members, as that would have been more descriptive for the purpose, but then I would have had to (re)write the Workflow as well :/

Answer (score 3):

Best example is `Async.Catch` where you either return a result or an exception, both of which are meaningful.

Having said that, the use of `Choice` is relatively limited in F# code and most of the time people use a DU.  However, a `Choice` might be used when you can't be bothered to define a DU.

`Choice` may also have better behavior when interacting with C#

Comment: Minor correction: it's [`Async.Catch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353899.aspx), not `Async.Try`.

Answer (score 3):

I have observed it's value when attempting to [enforce the creation of a discriminated union value via a dedicated function and Active Patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42230388/how-can-i-enforce-the-creation-of-a-discriminated-union-value-through-a-dedicate#42230980).

Here's the example that was posted:

```
module File1 =

    type EmailAddress = 
        private
        | Valid   of string 
        | Invalid of string

    let createEmailAddress (address:System.String) =
        if address.Length > 0
        then Valid    address 
        else Invalid  address

    // Exposed patterns go here
    let (|Valid|Invalid|) (input : EmailAddress) : Choice<string, string>  = 
        match input with
        |Valid str -> Valid str
        |Invalid str -> Valid str

module File2 =

    open File1

    let validEmail = Valid "" // Compiler error

    let isValid = createEmailAddress "" // works

    let result = // also works
        match isValid with
        | Valid x -> true
        | _       -> false
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same question 10 years later, and just wanted to summarize the places it is used in the official docs (spoiler: barely) as of 2023:

- **Pattern matching >** [**Active Patterns**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/active-patterns)

  In a comment at the very top:

  ```
  // Active Pattern with multiple choices.
  // Uses a FSharp.Core.Choice<_,...,_> based on the
  // number of case names. In F#, the limitation n <= 7 applies.

  let (|identifier1|identifier2|...|) valueToMatch = expression
  ```
- **Tutorials >** [**Async programming in F#**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/tutorials/async)

  It is mentioned 3 times when talking about `Async.Catch`.
- **F# style guide >** [**F# code formatting guidelines**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/style-guide/formatting)

  Used in a couple of places, but only for abbreviating the code.

---

The [Railway Oriented Programming: Carbonated Edition](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/railway-oriented-programming-carbonated/#fizzbuzz-the-railway-oriented-version) uses it to define a type with Active Patterns,

```
    let (|Success|Failure|) =
        function
        | Choice1Of2 s -> Success s
        | Choice2Of2 f -> Failure f
```

but the preceding article, [Railway Oriented Programming](https://swlaschin.gitbooks.io/fsharpforfunandprofit/content/posts/recipe-part2.html) uses a way simpler definition with the same functions:

```
type Result<'TSuccess,'TFailure> = 
    | Success of 'TSuccess
    | Failure of 'TFailure
```