# How can I enforce the creation of a Discriminated Union value through a dedicated function?

Tags: f#

How can I enforce the creation of a Discriminated Union value through a dedicated function?

**Intent:**

I want to rely on Creational Patterns to produce structures having valid data only.

Therefore, I believe that I will need to restrict the use of a DU value by making it read-only. However, it's not obvious to me how to accomplish that.

```
module File1 =

    type EmailAddress = 
        | Valid   of string 
        | Invalid of string

    let createEmailAddress (address:System.String) =
        if address.Length > 0
        then Valid    address 
        else Invalid  address

module File2 =

    open File1

    let validEmail = Valid "" // Shouldn't be allowed

    let isValid = createEmailAddress ""

    let result = match isValid with
                 | Valid x -> true
                 | _       -> false
```

**I tried the following:**

```
type EmailAddress =
    private
    | Valid   of string 
    | Invalid of string
```

However, setting the DU type as private breaks the ability to perform pattern matching on the result of the creation function.

Comment: Fwiw, the [F# component design guidelines](http://fsharp.org/specs/component-design-guidelines/#do-hide-the-representations-of-record-and-union-types-if-the-design-of-these-types-is-likely-to-evolve) similarly suggest to not expose DU types if they are bound to evolve and merely represent the inner state of your code.

Comment: Closely related, possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539870/how-to-do-argument-validation-of-f-records

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is just what springs to mind immediately.

You could use an active pattern to determine the cases you want to expose as an API to the outside world and then keep the internal representation of the DU completely private.

This would force you to use the publically exposed API to create the discriminated union but still allow pattern matching against the result - something like this:

```
module File1 =

    type EmailAddress = 
        private
        | Valid   of string 
        | Invalid of string

    let createEmailAddress (address:System.String) =
        if address.Length > 0
        then Valid    address 
        else Invalid  address

    // Exposed patterns go here
    let (|Valid|Invalid|) (input : EmailAddress) : Choice<string, string>  = 
        match input with
        | Valid str -> Valid str
        | Invalid str -> Invalid str

module File2 =

    open File1

    let validEmail = Valid "" // Compiler error

    let isValid = createEmailAddress "" // works

    let result = // also works
        match isValid with
        | Valid x -> true
        | _       -> false
```

Note that if you use the same pattern names, you may have to add the rather nasty type annotations shown above - these would be required to prevent a compiler error if the `File2` module were not present - this could be relevant if you are exposing an API in a library but not making use of it.  If you use different pattern names, that's obviously not an issue.

Comment: What's `Choice<string, string>` for?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin The result of an active pattern is a `Choice` parametrised by the type contained within each case.  Due to the reuse of the `Valid` and `Invalid` names, I have to make this explicit in the type annotation.

Comment: It actually works just fine without the annotation. Have you tried it? Even the annotation `input: EmailAddress` is unnecessary: the definition is not recursive, so there is no conflict between the DU cases and the active pattern labels. In fact, you can contract the whole thing to just `let (|Valid|Invalid|) = function ...`.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Yes I have tried it, I got a fairly explicit compiler error stating that I needed to do the above.  The `let (|Valid|Invalid|) = function` pattern was how I originally planned to write it.  I will check it again...

Comment: @FyodorSoikin On further investigation, the type annotation is not required but only if the above code is complete.  If the `File2` is not present, which contains the usage of the active pattern, you would get the compiler error that I mentioned.  I will edit the answer shortly to include this additional information.

Answer (score 3):

As you've discovered, the DU value names (`Valid` and `Invalid` in your example), used in pattern matches, are also the constructors of those respective cases. It is not possible to do what you're asking for, to hide one and expose the other. A different approach is needed.

One approach might be to do what Anton Schwaighofer suggests, and embed all the possible operations on your email addresses inside a dedicated module:

```
module EmailAddress =

    type EmailAddress =
        private
        | Valid   of string 
        | Invalid of string

    let createEmailAddress (address:System.String) =
        if address.Length > 0
        then Valid    address 
        else Invalid  address

    let isValid emailAddress =
        match emailAddress with
        | Valid _ -> true
        | Invalid _ -> false

    // Deliberately incomplete match in this function
    let extractEmailOrThrow (Valid address) = address

    let tryExtractEmail emailAddress =
        match emailAddress with
        | Valid s -> Some s
        | Invalid _ -> None
```

See Scott Wlaschin's "Designing with types" series, and in particular http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-more-semantic-types/ (and the [gist](https://gist.github.com/swlaschin/54cfff886669ccab895a) he references at the end of that). I'd really recommend reading from the beginning of the series, but I've linked the most relevant one.

**BUT**... I would suggest a different approach, which is to ask ***why*** you want to enforce the use of those constructor functions. Are you writing a library for general-purpose use by beginning programmers, who can't be trusted to follow the directions and use your constructor function? Are you writing just for yourself, but you don't trust *yourself* to follow your own directions? **OR**... are you writing a library for reasonably-competent programmers who will read the comment at the top of the code and actually use the constructor functions you've provided?

If so, then there's no particular need to enforce hiding the DU names. Just document the DU like so:

```
module EmailAddress =

    /// Do not create these directly; use the `createEmailAddress` function
    type EmailAddress =
        | Valid   of string 
        | Invalid of string

    let createEmailAddress (address:System.String) =
        if address.Length > 0
        then Valid    address 
        else Invalid  address
```

Then go ahead and write the rest of your code. Worry about getting your model right *first*, then you can worry about whether other programmers will use your code wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you want to do. One way would to expose the *states* as member functions and act on those. This works in your case but could become cumbersome with 3 or more value constructors.

```
type EmailAddress = 
    private
    | Valid   of string 
    | Invalid of string
with
    member this.IsValid() =
        match this with
             | Valid _ -> true
             | _ -> false
    member this.IsInvalid() = not <| this.IsValid()
```

Or you add a special `map` function

```
    member this.Map (success, error) =
        match this with
             | Valid x -> Valid (success x)
             | Invalid x -> Invalid (error x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42230980) implies, and what its commenters try to refute, my impression is that there is normally no need for type annotations. If you really *consider hiding the representations of discriminated unions for binary compatible APIs* as per [F# Component Design Guidelines](http://fsharp.org/specs/component-design-guidelines/#consider-hiding-the-representations-of-discriminated-unions-for-binary-compatible-apis-if-the-design-of-these-types-is-likely-to-evolve), a minimalistic and generic but complete reproduction could look like this:

```
module Foo =
    type 'a Foo =
        private | Bar of 'a 
        | Fred of string
    let mkBar a = Bar a 
    let mkFred<'a> s : 'a Foo = Fred s
    let (|Bar|Fred|) = function
    | Bar a -> Bar a
    | Fred s -> Fred s
```

The Union case constructors `Bar` and `Fred` are inaccessible from outside module `Foo`, and replaced by functions doubling as hooks for validation. For consumers, we have the Active recognisers `Bar` and `Fred` instead.

```
let bar = Foo.mkBar 42
let fred = Foo.mkFred<int> "Fred"

[Foo.mkBar 42; Foo.mkFred "Fred"]
|> List.filter (function Foo.Bar _ -> true | _ -> false)
```